# Java program to calculate and display tomorrow's date

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm attempting to write a program that receives a present date input, and then displays tomorrow's date.
I think it's almost complete, but something is going wrong when I test the present date variables to maxDays. I never get the correct date for tomorrow.

I think the problem with my code lies in this part. Thanks for taking a look!

```
if (((presentDay > maxDays || presentDay < 1)) || (presentMonth > 12)
            || (presentYear < 0)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter valid date \n\n"
                + "consider number of days in each month\n"
                + "entries must be greater than or equal to 1");
    } else {

        if (presentDay == maxDays) {
            if (presentMonth == 12) {
                tmrwDay = 1;
                tmrwMonth = 1;
                tmrwYear = presentYear++;
            } else {
                tmrwDay = 1;
                tmrwMonth = presentMonth++;
                tmrwYear = presentYear;
            }
        } else {
            tmrwDay = presentDay++;
            tmrwMonth = presentMonth;
            tmrwYear = presentYear;
        }

        displayTmrwDate(tmrwDay, tmrwMonth, tmrwYear);

    }
```

Here is the full program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lab5 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JTextField dayTextField, monthTextField, yearTextField;
private JLabel nextDateCalculatorLabel, presentDayLabel,
        presentMonthLabel, presentYearLabel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lab5 frame = new Lab5();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  //centers the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void createGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    nextDateCalculatorLabel = new JLabel("- - - - -" + "  "
            + "N e x t" + "  " + "D a y" + "  " + "C a l c u l a t o r"
            + "  " + "- - - - -");
    window.add(nextDateCalculatorLabel);

    presentDayLabel = new JLabel("Enter Present Day:");
    window.add(presentDayLabel);

    dayTextField = new JTextField(5);
    window.add(dayTextField);
    dayTextField.addActionListener(this);

    presentMonthLabel = new JLabel("Enter Present Month:");
    window.add(presentMonthLabel);

    monthTextField = new JTextField(5);
    window.add(monthTextField);
    monthTextField.addActionListener(this);

    presentYearLabel = new JLabel("Enter Present Year:");
    window.add(presentYearLabel);

    yearTextField = new JTextField(5);
    window.add(yearTextField);
    yearTextField.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    int presentDay, presentMonth, presentYear;
    int maxDays, tmrwDay, tmrwMonth, tmrwYear;
    String inputString;

    inputString = dayTextField.getText();
    presentDay = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    inputString = monthTextField.getText();
    presentMonth = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    inputString = yearTextField.getText();
    presentYear = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

    maxDays = calcMaxDays(presentMonth, presentYear);

    if (((presentDay > maxDays || presentDay < 1)) || (presentMonth > 12)
            || (presentYear < 0)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter valid date \n\n"
                + "consider number of days in each month\n"
                + "entries must be greater than or equal to 1");
    } else {

        if (presentDay == maxDays) {
            if (presentMonth == 12) {
                tmrwDay = 1;
                tmrwMonth = 1;
                tmrwYear = presentYear++;
            } else {
                tmrwDay = 1;
                tmrwMonth = presentMonth++;
                tmrwYear = presentYear;
            }
        } else {
            tmrwDay = presentDay++;
            tmrwMonth = presentMonth;
            tmrwYear = presentYear;
        }

        displayTmrwDate(tmrwDay, tmrwMonth, tmrwYear);

    }

}

private int calcMaxDays(int m, int y) {
    int maxDays = 0;

    switch (m) {

        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
            maxDays = 31;
            break;

        case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
            maxDays = 30;
            break;

        case 2:
            if ((y % 400 == 0) || (y % 100 != 0 && y % 4 == 0)) {
                maxDays = 29;
            } else {
                maxDays = 28;
            }
            break;
    }

    return maxDays;
}

private static void displayTmrwDate(int tD, int tM, int tY) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Date Tomorrow is:\n"
            + tD + "/" + tM + "/" + tY);
}
```

}

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This program should compile and run for us, and should demonstrate your problem for us. All we need are the logical parts of your code. There's no need to post any GUI code since it is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Demonstrate your problem in the shortest, self-contained correct example of code possible. No one is going to wade through all of that code based on a vague statement that "something is going wrong." Find out the specific area of code where the problem occurs and post that bit. Also, describe the problem fully and accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new to all of this. I will attempt to write something small that will reproduce my problem.

Comment: this `tmrwYear = presentYear++;`  (and other uses of `++` nearby) is supicious

Comment: @guido: good catch! Always do increments/decrements on their own line. The extra line costs nothing to you, and it can save you some sleepless nights of debugging!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is this a formatting thing for readability, or are you saying it's affecting my output?

Comment: It's a common source of bugs, since if not done extremely carefully, you'll make a mistake on your assumption of the order of operations, and use a variable that you thought has already been incremented when it hasn't or visa versa. You want to avoid writing *dangerous* code, code that can easily harbor bugs. It is for this same reason that I usually enclose **all** blocks, even single line if blocks, in curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a post-increment `presentDay++`  and you need to use a pre-increment `++presentDay` in every statement in your if statement.

For example in your statement:

```
tmrwDay = presentDay++;
```

First the value of `presentDay` is assigned to `tmrwDay` and then `presentDay`'s value is incremented. If you were to pre-increment, `++presentDay`, then `presentDay`'s value would increment and then assign it's value to `tmrwDay`.